# Porting C-style for-loops with non-trivial iteration and continue to Rust

Tags: for-loop, rust

EDIT: I don't think I've explained my question clearly enough, so here's another attempt (original question is below).

A C-style for loop has these parts and can be executed as follows:

```cpp
for (<initialisation>; <condition>; <iteration>)
{
    <body1>
    if (some_state1)
        continue; // short circuit to the next iteration
    <body2>
    if (some_state2)
        continue; // short circuit to the next iteration
    <body3>
    if (some_state3)
        continue; // short circuit to the next iteration
    <body4>
}

// Program execution:
...
<initialisation>
<condition>
<body1>
<body2>
continue // quick out because of 'some_state2'
<iteration>
<condition>
<body>
...
```

I know for-loops in Rust operate on iterators, so the nearest equivalent to the psuedo code above is a `while` or `loop`.

Is there a language construct in Rust that results in the same program execution as above?

The best I can come up with is the following which duplicates the iteration code before every `continue` and at the end of the loop. Other alternatives introduce extra variables and/or additional tests.

```rust
<initialisation>
while <condition> {
    
    <body1>
    if some_state1 {
        <iteration>
        continue;
    }
    <body2>
    if some_state2 {
        <iteration>
        continue;
    }
    <body3>
    if some_state3 {
        <iteration>
        continue;
    }
    <body4>
    <iteration>
}
```

This would produce the correct program execution, but isn't valid Rust code.

```rust
<initialisation>
while <condition> {

    <body1>
    if some_state1 {
        goto label;
    }
    <body2>
    if some_state2 {
        goto label;
    }
    <body3>
    if some_state3 {
        goto label;
    }
    <body4>
label:
    <iteration>
}
```

PREVIOUS:

There are many articles about converting C-style for-loops to Rust, but almost all ignore non-trivial use of the iteration part of a for loop when used in conjunction with continue.

For example, how do you succinctly implement the following pseudo C++ in Rust?

```cpp
struct SomeData { ... };

SomeData data;
for (auto done = false; !done; done = next(data))
{
    if (!condition1(data))
        continue; // on to the next one

    if (!condition2(data))
        continue; // on to the next one
        
    if (!condition3(data))
        continue; // on to the next one
        
    // All conditions met, 
    process(data);
}
```

The first choice is a while loop with increasing nesting, but this gets uglier as the number of conditions grows, and there is nowhere to put a breakpoint when one of the conditions isn't met.

```rust
let mut data = SomeData::new();
let mut done = false;              // scope lives beyond the loop

while !done {
    if condition1(&data) {
        if condition2(&data) {
            if condition3(&data) { // nesting gets ugly fast..
                process(data);
            }                      // can't breakpoint on !condition3
        }                          // without editing the code
    }
    done = next(&mut data);     
}
```

Another option is to introduce an unnecessary boolean and conditional:

```rust
let mut data = SomeData::new();
let mut done = false;              // scope lives beyond the loop
while !done {
    let mut is_good = true;        // useless variable
    if !condition1(data) {
        is_good = false;
    }
    if is_good && !condition2(data) {
        is_good = false;
    }
    if is_good && !condition3(data) {
        is_good = false;
    }
    if is_good {
        process(data);
    }
    done = next(&mut data);
}
```

Comment: Remember that conditions short-circuit, so you can do `if condition1(data) && condition2(data) && condition3(data) { process(data); }`

Comment: I'd encourage you to use iterators more. Otherwise, use a `loop` with a `break`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be most idiomatic to convert the code to use an `Iterator`, but that is "non-trivial" in this case due to how next works. The simplest version I  could create was to create that was similar to the C code yet IMO reasonably idiomatic was to create an `on_each` style function that accepts a closure.

```
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct SomeData {}

fn next(data: &mut SomeData) -> bool {todo!() }
fn process(data: &mut SomeData) { todo!() }
fn condition1(data: &SomeData) -> bool { todo!() }
fn condition2(data: &SomeData) -> bool { todo!() }
fn condition3(data: &SomeData) -> bool { todo!() }

pub fn on_each_data(f: impl for<'a> Fn(&'a mut SomeData)) {
    let mut data = SomeData::default();
    f(&mut data);
    while next(&mut data) {
        f(&mut data);
    }
}

pub fn iterate_data_2() {
    on_each_data(|data| {
        if condition1(data) {
            return;
        }
        if condition2(data) {
            return;
        }
        if condition3(data) {
            return;
        }
        process(data)
    });
}
```

Comment: Michael, thank you for your answer. Refactoring the loop body into another function or closure so that `return` can be used instead of `continue` is a good idea. I agree that converting the code to use iterators is the preferred option when it makes sense, but not every loop can be cleanly represented with iterators.

Answer (score 2):

`for` loops in Rust act on iterators, so if you want succinct semantics, change your code to use them. There's not really that much other choice - what's ergonomic in C isn't necessarily ergonomic in Rust, and vice versa.

If your `next` functions follow a common pattern, you can create a structure that implements `Iterator` that takes the `next` function as a `FnMut` closure.

In my opinion, your "useless variable" is only there because you've special cased getting the first element by doing it without the `next` function. If you changed your code so that `next(None)` returns the first item, you wouldn't need that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Shepmaster. I see your point about the ```next``` function. I am also aware of iterators and use them frequently, but the point of my question was that Rust doesn't seem to have a loop mechanism for this particular control flow. A while-loop iterates 0 or more times with short circuit to the start of the loop, a do-while loop iterates 1 or more times with short circuit to the end of the loop, for-loops iterate 0 or more times with short circuit to the logic that advances the iterator. This last flow is the awkward one.

Comment: @Dwighte I posted the answer; Shepmaster edited it. The fact is, 99% of the time in C (including this one), for loops are used for iteration, so Rust cuts out the middle man. It's not worth having a dedicated loop type that no one will use, when you can emulate its behavior or write it the right way.

Comment: Oh, my apologies. Thank you for the answer.  I agree that 99% of the time Rust's loop options lead to better code. But in the 1% of times where they don't, I think the missing language constructs force every user to implement their own (possibly incorrect) work arounds. I'm still not exactly sure how my example would be implemented using iterators. When you say "a loop type that no one will use", I know I wanted to use it...

Comment: If you have the time, could you provide a pseudo code implementation based on iterators? I'm still learning rust so it would be educational. I understand if you don't want to. Thanks again for taking the time to answer.